What do you recommend as the best way to feed watermelon?
My planting scheme is relatively small: 70cm*100cm. I planted watermelon from seedlings, but I want to know from you what they fertilize in the West. Because in Ukraine we have organic or chemical fertilizers (but mostly chemical).

Hello, and welcome to the site.  Links to your website should be clearly noted as your own website, and should only be included when they are integral to the question.  You can repeat the watermelon planting method here if you feel it is relevant to the question, or leave it out if not.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion

See https://gardening.stackexchange.com/help/promotion on the expected behavior w/r to your own site.
